# My Code turns on my LED even when my switch is not pressed

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, switch

I am trying to create a circuit that will turn my motor when I clap. When the first limit switch is low, and there is only one clap, a solenoid pin is supposed to be engaged (currently an LED), but when I clap once without pressing the limit switch, my LED turns on.

Also, I can't seem to get my code to work properly with the limit switches, to control my motor.

I am not sure what is wrong, can someone help?

I have an Arduino Uno with the following code:

```
#define sound_Sensor 2
#define EN1 9
#define IN1 8
#define IN2 7
#define solenoid_pin 6
#define LimSwitch1 4
#define LimSwitch2 3

int lastSoundValue;
int soundValue;
long lastNoiseTime = 0;
long currentNoiseTime = 0;
int solenoidPinStatus = LOW;
int status_motor = LOW;
int clap_interval = 200;
int claps = 0;
int pos1 = 1;
int pos2 = 1;

void setup() {
  pinMode(sound_Sensor, INPUT);
  pinMode(EN1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(IN1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(IN2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(solenoid_pin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LimSwitch1, INPUT);
  pinMode(LimSwitch2, INPUT);
}

void loop() {

  soundValue = digitalRead(sound_Sensor);
  currentNoiseTime = millis();
  if (soundValue == 1 && lastSoundValue == 0 && (currentNoiseTime > lastNoiseTime + 200)) 
  { 
      if (claps == 0) // allow first to register without much condition
      {
          claps = 1;
          lastNoiseTime = currentNoiseTime;
      }
      else
      {
          if (currentNoiseTime > lastNoiseTime + clap_interval)
          {
              claps++;
              lastNoiseTime = currentNoiseTime;
          }
      }
      Serial.print(claps);
  }
  else
  {
      if (currentNoiseTime > (lastNoiseTime + 3 * clap_interval)) // no claps for a longer duration time to print and/or reset clap
      {
          if (claps > 0)
          {
              while(status_motor == LOW){
                  if (digitalRead(LimSwitch1) == LOW && claps == 1)
                  {
                    solenoidPinStatus = HIGH;
                    digitalWrite(solenoid_pin, HIGH);     
                  }

                 if (digitalRead(LimSwitch1) == LOW)
                 {
                    pos1 = 2;
                    status_motor = HIGH;
                    digitalWrite(IN1, HIGH); //Turns on Motor
                    digitalWrite(IN2, LOW);
                    analogWrite(EN1, 200); //Set Speed of Motor
                  }
                 else if (digitalRead(LimSwitch2) == LOW)
                 {
                    pos2 = 2;
                    status_motor = HIGH;
                    digitalWrite(IN1, HIGH); //Turns on Motor99++
                    digitalWrite(IN2, LOW);
                    analogWrite(EN1, 200); //Set Speed of Motor
                 }
              }

              while(status_motor == HIGH){
                if (pos1 == 2 && digitalRead(LimSwitch2) == LOW)
                {
                    status_motor = LOW;
                    digitalWrite(IN1, LOW); //Turns on Motor
                    digitalWrite(IN2, LOW);
                    pos1 = 1;
                }

                else if (pos2 == 2 && digitalRead(LimSwitch1) == LOW)
                {
                    status_motor = LOW;
                    digitalWrite(IN1, LOW); //Turns on Motor
                    digitalWrite(IN2, LOW);
                    pos2 = 1;
                }
              }
          }
             claps = 0; ///reset
      }
  }

// if (solenoidPinStatus == HIGH && status_motor == LOW && digitalRead(LimSwitch1) == LOW)
// {
//   solenoidPinStatus = LOW;
//   digitalWrite(solenoid_pin, LOW);
// }
  lastSoundValue = soundValue;
}
```

Sorry my wire diagram may not be the easiest to look at...

Comment: what is the voltage across Limitsw1 output pin.

Comment: how are the switches wired? do you have pull-down resistors?

Comment: Where is the diagram?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem might be connected to wiring.

This is one of the ways you can correctly connect a switch to Pin 8.

[image: Arduino with switch]

In this case you need to configure Pin 8 as INPUT_PULLUP to use internal "pullup" resistor. When switch is not pressed Pin8 is connected to 5V through that resistor and value on the pin is HIGH. When you press the switch it connects Pin 8 to ground (the resistor prevents a short) and that way value on Pin 8 is LOW.

This is code that works correctly with the design above

```
void setup()
{
  pinMode(8, INPUT_PULLUP);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  if (digitalRead(8) == HIGH)
  {
    Serial.println("It's HIGH");
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("It's LOW");
  }

  delay(1000);
}
```

If you do not configure Pin 8 as INPUT_PULLUP but just normal INPUT (as you did in your code) when the button is not pressed Pin 8 is "floating" (it's not connected to anything) and on a "floating" pin values are random.